# Name of subset of $X$ consisting of those elements $x$ fixed by a given subgroup $F \leq G$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Suppose that a group $G$ acts on a set $X$. Given $x \in X$, denote by $G_x$ the stabiliser subgroup of $G$ with respect to $x$, i.e. the subgroup of $G$ comprising all $g \in G$ which fix $x$. Now suppose that $F$ is a subgroup of $G$, and consider the set $\{x \in X : F \text{ is the stabiliser subgroup of } G \text{ with respect to } x\}$. What is the name of this set ?

Answer (score 1):

In french we sometimes use $Fix_g = \{x\in X : g(x) = x\}$

but I advise you against using it as it is sometimes used in english to mean

$G_T = Fix_G(T) = \{g\in G : g(x) = x, \forall x\in T\}$

I am unaware if any other notations exist.

Comment: Thank you very much J. Sadek. It is not immediately obvious to me that $\bigcap_{g\in F} \textit{Fix}_g$ is the same as my set. I want those elements of $X$ which are fixed by every $g \in F$, but *not* fixed by any $g \in G \setminus F$.

Comment: you are completely right

Comment: In case it is of interest, my aim was to count the orbits of $X$ under the action of $G$. I did it by dividing the size of the set that I am trying to name by the size of the subgroup $F$, and summing the result over all subgroups $F$ of $G$.

After reading your reply, J. Sadek, I learned about the Cauchy-Frobenius lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma. In my case, this gives an easier way to count the orbits, because it is easier for me to write down the sizes of the sets $X^g$, or as you call them, $\text{Fix}_g$, than to write down the sizes of my nameless sets.